# What type of transformer is this?

Tags: transformer, components

I have a design project for my electrical engineering class where I'm designing a signal tracer akin to Tripplett's Fox and Hound series.

For a reference, I tested the output of a commercial tone generator to see what kind of signal I'd need to generate for it to be received by the handset and found a 40 VPP square wave(well above the 3V from the batteries) so I assumed there must be a transformer. I opened the case and identified a tiny little transformer, about a 1 cm cube.

I tested my own generator with a standard power transformer with a 1:10 ratio and it worked fine, but it's rather bulky for something that could be much smaller. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what I should be searching for.

SMPS transformers all appear to be rated for 40khz or more, and I'm only outputting 2khz. Is it just a custom wound thing? If not, what should I be looking for on digikey/mouser?

The picture isn't very good, but it only has 2 leads per winding, no taps.

I'm using 9v rather than 3v input, so I need about a 1:5 ratio...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a first pass, I'd say you are probably looking for an "audio transformer".

Update: I'm a bit concerned whether you're fully aware of the type of signal you need. Is this intended to test phone wiring? If so you might want to read this:

http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/teleinterface.html

I don't think you need 40V signals for them to be audible in a phone handset. Indeed, I recall connecting them via 1:1 transformer to record them on a tape recorder, which suggests signals in the 1V range.

Comment: I thought that might be it, but all the audio transformers I found seem to be impedance matching (1:1), there isn't even anything pertaining to signal level except insertion loss for the audio xformers on digikey.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: While it isn't strictly necessary to have 40v ( I could probably get by with ~8 v) A signal that weak makes it difficult to use. The tools are used to trace wires through walls and the like without making contact. As far as I've been able to figure out, it basically turns the line it's hooked into into an antenna, and the handset is an RF recceiver. Akin to http://www.amazon.com/Triplett-3399-Fox-Hound-Probe/dp/B001ULPREW. If it were just connected via wires, you're right, 1V would be fine.

Comment: I looked in the manual for the Triplett device you mentioned http://www.triplett.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Fox-Hound-3399-Instruction-Manual.pdf and I'm not seeing any mention of signals higher than 12Vp-p, nor of an "antenna" mode (presumably capacitive coupling between parallel wires?) Perhaps I'm missing something. And you are aware that phone lines have an ~50V DC bias, right?

Comment: You likely are. It's not an "antenna mode," that's the theory of operation. You connect a generator to the wires. You then hold the "wand" and push a button, at which point it picks up the signal and emits it through a speaker in the "wand."

Whether or not you see signals like that in the manual, that's what it was outputting on my oscope, and generating that with my signal generator, which I ran through a power transformer and adjusted to the same 40 volts, that worked. I actually got it to about 100 vpp and was able to pick up the signal about three feet from the wire.

Comment: The use I'm referring to is around page 34 in the manual you linked.

Comment: Ah, sorry, apparently I skipped an important part of the manual. I thought the two parts of the product were to attach to two ends of cable. Instead, the "hound" part is to sniff out signals in wires capacitively at a distance. (Note to self, see section 7.6).

Comment: I notice the specs (page 9) say that the tracer tone is a "differentiated square wave". That suggests sharp pulses at what would be square-wave transitions. That is likely to produce a large amount of higher-frequency signal. This might be a way to generate more detectable signal with smaller supply voltage range, and not needing a transformer? Do you have any insight into whether that's what the Fox actually does?

Comment: It does use square waves. They measure at 44 volts peak to peak. I can show you the image I saved from my oscope if you don't believe me :P

http://www.neatcircuits.com/foxhound/index.html
That's what I'm working from, though I'm using a 555 timer instead of the NOR gates. My parter is doing the hound part.

The square wave is certainly more audible than triangle or sine (I tested those too). I may be able to do it without a transformer but that's not really necessary; a power transformer *works* it's just not ideal.

Comment: I've looked at other schematics and asked questions here about how it works, and generally it all seems to hinge around the handset working as an active antenna, coupled via the user's body.

Comment: Yes, I'm buying the principle of operation. I'm just curious how the "12Vp-p" of the Triplett specs corresponds to what you measured. Are you actually measuring the Triplett, or some other unit?

Comment: I see the neatcircuits fox circuit produces approx 8.5Vp-p square wave that's capacitively coupled to the phone line, so it's that output capacitor that might be called the "differentiation".

Comment: One possibility for a larger voltage output: Throw in a small DC-DC boost converter, and then have the output stage switch across that voltage. This would avoid needing a transformer, and its possible waveform-modifying (and high-frequency reducing) characteristics.

Comment: I'm not measuring the output of a tripllett, no. I probably should have been more clear on that, sorry. A boost converter could indeed work, but so does the simple power transformer sitting on my desk right now(because I've done it), I'm just looking for a small one.

Comment: Ah, OK. However, the discussion may have usefully suggested that it's the higher-frequency components of the test signal that are most useful, and that a suitable transformer need not be good at the fundamental frequency, but should be good for higher frequencies. That might broaden the field a bit.

Comment: fundamental frequency?

Comment: Fundamental = 2kHz. But square, and differentiated square are going to have lots of power at multiples of that frequency, and those will radiate/couple to hound more than the fundamental frequency. As you noted with your comparison of square, triangle and sine.

Comment: I found a bunch of impedance matching transformers, some of which have ratios in the right ballpark, and other characteristics which might work. Can't seem to find detailed specs and complete range of alternatives though: http://www.passivecomponent.org/electronic/impedance-matching.html

Comment: Oh, fundamental as in the source of the harmonics(I'd read something about square waves being illegal to transmit because of bandwidth saturation from the harmonics while I was researching this)

Aren't those impedance matching transformers 1:1?

Comment: Well, the fundamental is, by definition, the base-frequency sinusoidal component of the signal that is _not_ a harmonic. The harmonics correspond to any non-sinusoidal features of the signal of interest. A square wave produces harmonics at odd multiples of the fundamental. Transformers: The ST-53 has a 750-350 ratio. Not quite what you wanted, but suggests others might be out there. But annoyingly few specs. (And the eBay pic shows ST-52, not 53!)

Comment: A problem is that audio transformer have, I believe, mostly fallen out of use. So hard to get. And most are used for input (Mic to high-Z) and output (1k or so to 8 ohms), neither close to your application.

Comment: Isn't the 750-350 they're listing the impedance, not the winding ratio?

Comment: I'm assuming it's the impedance that each side of the transformer is intended to match, hence an indication of winding ratio and absolute quantity of turns. But this is frustratingly short of reliable specs.

Comment: Well. I appreciate the help. I think I'll just stick with the power transformer for now, go with what I know works. If I have time before the presentation I might try a boost converter.